# Excel - how to store several words into one combined substring

Tags: excel, string, substring

I am working with a document, where each row contains a description for a specific incident (fire incidents, where firefighters turn up and thereafter write a report). 
The incidents/reports are written by several different people, so the language varies a lot, which makes it difficult to code for one specific context using one word: `is.number(search(substring;text))` 
Because even if the word is in the text piece, the context is not related to what I am trying to analyse.

I want to broaden my word search to be more flexible, by being able to "put" or "store" several different words/phrases into my "substring" - being able to get closer to the specific context that I wish to analyse. 
This way to cover more data that is in fact related, but different in how it is described in the individual incident reports.

I have tried to search for a solution myself, but am unsure on how to phrase this specific inquiry.

So far I have only been able to use the code piece above, which is a bit insufficient, when trying to comb through 2000 rows.

I hope that someone is able to help me!

Thank you

***An example:*** 
Store the following words: *stopped fire, killed fire, fire was put out* into: **Killed fire**

So that when I use **Killed fire** all the above wordings are included in my search.

Comment: a) you might want to add a programming language tag to your question b) provide a small sample with expected results.

Comment: Pleae put some sample cell value... I assume you have a seperate table containing keywords you're using,by them you're assigning tags... or how dobyou do it? in any case dynamic text search is not for excel alone.. . unless the tagging system is simple

Comment: I have tried adding an example of what I mean. 
Regarding programming language, I am using microsoft excel - I don't know what else to call it.

Comment: If the example is still not good enough - I will try something else.

Comment: Make a Master_Table with those words: That list could have 2 columns: First column would be, for each row, those words you are looking for (*stopped fire, killed fire, fire was put out*). Second column would be the concept (**Killed fire**). Then, with normal excel formulas, you could count each group of words in additional columns and that could maybe help you out to make your data table.